# How custom data type works in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

What does the following SQL statement do in case of SQLite?

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time STRFTIME);
```

Note that the `time` column has the `STRFTIME` type which is not listed in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

I guess that the following `INSERT` works without any errors

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (time) VALUES('text');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM foo;
1|text
```

because of this:

> 3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity
>
> The affinity of a column is determined by the declared type of the
>   column, according to the following rules in the order shown:
>
> 1. If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned
>      INTEGER affinity.
> 2. If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR",
>      "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the
>      type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT
>      affinity.
> 3. If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no
>      type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.
> 4. If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL",
>      "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
>
> **5. Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC**.

and this:

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five
>   storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the
>   storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of
>   preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible. For
>   conversions between TEXT and REAL storage classes, SQLite considers
>   the conversion to be lossless and reversible if the first 15
>   significant decimal digits of the number are preserved. **If the
>   lossless conversion of TEXT to INTEGER or REAL is not possible then
>   the value is stored using the TEXT storage class. No attempt is made
>   to convert NULL or BLOB values**

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; `STRFTIME` has exactly the same affinity as `FLUFFY BUNNIES`, i.e., numeric.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to implement a new type, it still must be stored internally in one of the sqlite primitive types. You then must provide functions to convert from python to sqlite and vice versa.

Here are the steps to perform:

- Use `sqlite3.register_adapter` to specify how to convert python type to sqlite. Although you could convert to one of sqlite internal/primitive types (text, integer, real, blob and null), you should use TEXT to be able to convert back (see next point).
- Use `sqlite3.register_converter` to specify how to convert from sqlite internal representation back to the python type.
- When calling `connect()`, specify the `detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES` argument.
- When you create a table, use the custom type name.

Note: the `register_converter` documentation says that you must convert from a bytestring.

Here is an example to implement a custom 'date' type:

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import date

def date_to_str(d):   # for python to sqlite
  return '%04d%02d%02d' % ( d.year, d.month, d.day )
def str_to_date(s):   # for sqlite to python
  y=int(s[0:4])
  m=int(s[4:6])
  d=int(s[6:8])
  return date(y,m,d)

sqlite3.register_adapter(date,date_to_str)
sqlite3.register_converter('date',str_to_date)

WEEKDAYS = {
  0: "Mon", 1: "Tue", 2: "Wed", 3: "Thu", 4: "Fri", 5:"Sat",6:"Sun"
}
def test():
  s = sqlite3.connect('myfile.dat', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
  c = s.cursor()
  c.execute('create table t1(id integer primary key, d1 date)')
  c.execute('insert into t1 values(?,?)', (1, date(2016,9,24)))
  c.execute('insert into t1 values(?,?)', (2, date(2000,1,1)))
  s.commit()
  for r_id, r_date in c.execute('select id,d1 from t1 order by d1'):
    print r_id, r_date, r_date.year, r_date.month, r_date.day, WEEKDAYS[r_date.weekday()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
  test()
```

While I was typing my answer, I read the accepted answer, and realized this was not your question.  However, if this can help other people...